# Failed to start Snap Daemon

Tags: snap, services

I am trying to install Lubuntu on a machine that has Ubuntu on it (BOTH LATEST VERSION)

When I boot with ISO disk it says loading Lubuntu for a long then it says:
OK Finished Plymouth boot
OK Finished Set Console scheme
FAILED Failed to start Snap Daemon

Then the machine is locked up and I must turn it off to reboot

I used another Lununtu DVD but same result

Can you help me??????

Comment: I'll suggest you use non-DVD media for install, as it'll save you grief, and will accomplish the install far faster. You can peruse this [thread on Lubuntu's discourse](https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/bug-failed-snap-daemon-in-lubuntu-22-04-lts-no-firefox-help-please/3246) but the summary is DVD installs are possible, but may take a few tries. Ubuntu no longer intends installations be done from DVD media (*hasn't for awhile*) and thus timeout issues (esp. with *snap* packages)..  This is on a bug that may see fix with 22.04.1 but it's low priority only (*meaning if resources allow*).

Comment: Please be specific as to what you mean by *latest*.  I'm assuming Lubuntu 22.04 LTS, but as google offers downloads from the official site, fan sites & fake sites - what you downloaded maybe a legitimate ISO, an *outdated* or even worse a *fake* ISO so be specific and issues can be avoided. Unlikely you may also mean a *daily* but which daily? as unless you're specific I cannot know...

Comment: Also FYI:  The machine should **not** be locked up, as myself & other team members had no issues exploring on systems using DVD media even when problems were encountered.  This highlights other potential issues (*you didn't use an official site & may not have a legit/latest ISO at all*) or other potential causes..  You should be able to switch to text terminal, use SysRq commands direct to kernel etc even if the GUI is lagging (*it should right itself, but 10+ mins maybe required; as some DVD installs took an hour+ as media scans aren't written for optical media & are inefficient there*)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot)

Answer (score 0):

Go to a login window:
Alt-f2
Login with user lubuntu and no password.
Check the journalctl as Juan suggests.
After several failures my snapd had started successfully. But you can now restart it if it failed.
Hit Alt-f1 and you may have a Gui running.